# Form initiates POST request for all but one case

Tags: python, sqlite, http, flask, werkzeug

I'm building a simple web app that displays the logged-in users hardware asset register of sorts. In my Html page I have an accordion with a table as follows:

```
<tbody>
{% for hard in HARDWARE %}
<tr>
    <td>
        <form action="{{url_for('del_hardware', id=hard.id)}}" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
        </form>
    </td>
    <td>{{ hard.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ hard.description }}</td>
    <td>{{ hard.purchased }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

in my application.py file I then have the following code:

```
@app.route('/del_hardware/<string:id>', methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def del_hardware(id):

    db.execute("UPDATE hardware SET actioned ='D' WHERE id=:hid", hid=id)

    return redirect("/")
```

for whatever reason, the route does not work for the first record in the table.

1. Clicking the Delete button for the first record in the table:

   No request is shown, the page reloads or is redirected to "/".
2. Clicking the Delete button for every other record in the table: I get the following request

   INFO:werkzeug:...[23/Dec/2019 10:31:42] "POST /del_hardware/**4** HTTP/1.0" 302 -

   where 4 is the ID of the device in the hardware table, and it works fine - The SQL 
   statement is executed and I'm redirected to "/" as intended.

Any help would be appreciated, apologies if I haven't described the issue that well or if i've simply overlooked a silly mistake somewhere.

Comment: I would suggest you to get back a bit and check the value of 'HARDWARE' which you have passed in the render_template of html provided above in application.py. print(HARDWARE) to check what contents are you getting in this variable.

Comment: H, thank you for your prompt response. I have checked and can confirm that the correct values are being passed into HARDWARE. The id of the first record in the table is 2, when I click the delete button i'm expecting INFO:werkzeug:...[23/Dec/2019 10:31:42] "POST /del_hardware/2 HTTP/1.0" 302, but nothing happens.

Comment: Make sure the HTML is valid?

Comment: the ```{% endfor %}``` looks like it could be moved a line up and should be above the ```</tbody>```

Comment: checked the HTML and the code and can't seem to find anything on why the app is not recognising the Post request... and the strangest thing is that it only affects the first element (or row) in the table..